# Javascript and jQuery both stop removing options in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a situation that I have ran into. The code below just dies when trying to remove something with a hyphen in it. I cannot find anyone else having this issue...

Has anyone else ran into this? What do you do as a work-a-round?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
Select a fruit:
<br>
<select id="mySelect" size="4">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Not-Happening</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
</form>

<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Remove selected fruit</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");

for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    alert(x.length);
    x.remove(i);
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the code below...

```
$(".mySelect").find("option").each(function(index, el){
  var $el = $(el);
  var value != '' $el.attr("value");
  if (value === "" || value === undefined)
    $el.remove();
});
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle

Comment: Just run it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_remove

Comment: You jQuery does not make sense. Starting with the `$(".mySelect")` selector (your select does not have a class name). And `var value != '' $el.attr("value");` would thow an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the hyphen, it's just that you're doing this:

```
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    alert(x.length);
    x.remove(i);
}
```

When you remove the option at index 0, all the others move up, but your `i` variable moves to 1. So the option was at index 1 is now at index 0 and doesn't get removed.

If you want to remove them all, either count backward, or assign to `length`:

```
x.length = 0;
```

If you just want to remove *selected* ones, work backward:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var i;
  for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (x[i].selected) {
      x[i].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var i;
  for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (x[i].selected) {
      x[i].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
Select some before clicking the button.
<form>
  Select a fruit:
  <br>
  <select id="mySelect" size="4">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Not-Happening</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>

<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Remove selected fruit</button>
```

With jQuery, it's simpler because jQuery is set-based and you can just remove them all at once:

```
$("#mySelect option:selected").remove();
```

Example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#mySelect option:selected").remove();
}
```

```html
Select some before clicking the button.
<form>
  Select a fruit:
  <br>
  <select id="mySelect" size="4">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Not-Happening</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>

<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Remove selected fruit</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Fidelis: Glad to help! I've added a jQuery example at the end as well, since you mentioned using jQuery.